# Getting a warning upon launch on different PCs

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have recently migrated from Kinetic and/or Indigo to Melodic, using Ubuntu 18.

My codes work fine but I keep getting the same message about a dozen times when launching a launch file:

```
XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2
```

It repeats for about a dozen times after launching, but does not seem to effect the runtime. I just find it strange that this happens on 3 different computers with different launch files / nodes, and I can't find a thing on the internet.

Not sure which node causes this, I can check, but maybe someone here knows about a setting I might be able to change to get rid of this.

Blessings,
Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319983/getting-a-warning-upon-launch-on-different-pcs/) by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2019-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-31**:
From a quick Google (searching for `XmbTextListToTextProperty result code` returns quite a few results) this appears to be an <del>Xorg server</del> Qt related error. I can't find the cause immediately, but various posts report that partial upgrades (of the OS) are too blame.

This does not seem to be directly related to ROS, other than the fact that many ROS UI tools use Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have run into this myself but having the solutions not working I deemed it coincidental.
I eventually found out the reason: Clash between the locale and some library (which QT probably uses too). I realized that Wireshark is also spitting out the same thing.
Ended up changing the locale as a workaround. Well then, I guess I'll have to stick to Imperial units n stuff. Not my cup of tea but anyway...
Thanks all.

---

Originally posted by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) with karma: 167 on 2019-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-01**:
You cannot change the locale back?

From some of the Google results I got the impression that changing to a different locale and then changing back actually solved it as well.